# Confusion about infinite order groups, subgroups and comparing order between them.

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

I was given feedback for a homework problem,

Let $G$ be a group. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $a \in G$. Let $Ha$ be a subgroup of $G$.

The problem was to show that $Ha = H$.

I established that $H \subset Ha$ and then I made the argument that since $Ha = \{ha \vert h \in H\}$, $\vert Ha \vert \leq \vert H \vert$
so $H = Ha$

I was marked wrong and given the justification that $\vert Ha \vert \leq \vert H \vert$ isn't valid if $\vert H \vert = \infty$

I wanted to understand why, as I think the point still holds that $Ha$ can have at most as many elements as $H$, so if $H$ is a subset of $Ha$ then $H = Ha$.

Comment: Yes, if $H\subset Ha$ then $H=Ha$, but you can't infer that on cardinality grounds, however there is an algebraic proof.

Comment: I understand that there is another solution, my question was why my method isn't correct.

Comment: I think your teacher may refer to cases as $2\mathbb{Z}\leq \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Wouldn't it be fair to say that $\vert 2Z \vert \leq \vert Z \vert$ as every element of $2Z$ is generated by a multiplication between a number in $Z$ and $2$? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: Z is the set of all integers and 2Z is the set of all even integers.  Obviously they are NOT the same set but have the same cardinality- they are both countably infinite.

Comment: @Nerdlord The problem is not $|Ha|\leq |H|$, that is true and not too hard to see, but how to conlude from that that $H=Ha$?